# how to change JSON Nested array property "project_id" with "project_name"

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

Trouble:

```js
[
{
"project_id": 1,
"project_name": "CDP",
"role": "PL"
},
{
"project_id": 2,
"project_name": "Admincer",
"role": "PM"
},
```

I want to add the "project_id" property from the above three properties to another array using some method.

My idea is: 1. First of all, if I could copy the "project_id" property of this array to the second Nested JSON array, it would be fine.

What I looked up:

```js
const obj = {
"project_id": 1,
"project_name": "CDP",
"role": "PL"
};;
const objCopy = {
"start_time": "09:00:00",
"end_time": "18:00:00",
"rest_time": "01:00:00",
"worked_time": "08:00:00",
"is_wfh": true,
"id": 1, 1,
"work_day_id": 45,
"time_cards": [
{
... obj
}
]
};;
console.log (objCopy);
```

I found that I could copy it this way.
I tried the above code in Chrome Console.
The array was copied, but the entire object was copied. I just want to copy the properties of project_id.

I want to create a new property called "prj_name" in this array and display only that property in Vuetify.

```js
async fetchWorkerTimeCard() {
  try {
    this.worker_data = [] 
    await this.$axios.$get('/worker_time_card', {
      params: {
        work_date: this.calendarVal
      }
    }).then(data => {
      this.worker_data = data
    })
    var projects = await this.fetch_worker_projects()
    console.log(projects)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    this.worker_data = []
  }
},
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.5/vue.js"></script>
<v-card>
  <v-data-table v-if="worker_data.time_cards" :headers="headers2" :items="worker_data.time_cards"></v-data-table>
</v-card>
```

Comment: it's not JSON once you JSON.parse it, it's an object, so treat it like any other object in javascript

Comment: `I just want to copy the properties of project_id` ... that's the value `1` in the code you posted - the thing is, your first data is an array of objects, and `obj` is a single object ... so, find the correct object from the array (Array's find method) before adding it as you do

Comment: `new property called "prj_name" in this array` which array? what should be the content of `prj_name`? can you reorganise your question to include 1. input data (i.e. existing data and whatever it is you're getting from the request, and 2. expected output data

Comment: my question is {how to change JSON Nested array property "project_id" with "project_name"}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your object data like any other object in JS.

```
const obj = {
  "project_id": 1,
  "project_name": "CDP",
  "role": "PL"
};

const objCopy = {
  "start_time": "09:00:00",
  "end_time": "18:00:00",
  "rest_time": "01:00:00",
  "worked_time": "08:00:00",
  "is_wfh": true,
  "id": 1,
  "work_day_id": 45
}

console.log({...obj, ...objCopy})
```

This will create 1 object that merged.

Or if you just want to project_id value then just change it like:

```
objCopy.project_id = obj.project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your first question correctly, you might be interested in the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which allows you to create a new array from an existing array. So, for example, if the first snippet you posted is an array of objects we call `projects`, you could use:
`var projectIds = projects.map(p => p.project_id)`, where projectIds would now be an array of just project ids.

It seems like you might be asking more than this though, so I second Bravo's request for more clarification/reorganization in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure if you want either of the following results:

```
{
"start_time": "09:00:00",
"end_time": "18:00:00",
"rest_time": "01:00:00",
"worked_time": "08:00:00",
"is_wfh": true,
"id": [
    1,
    1
],
"work_day_id": 45,
"time_cards": [
    {
        "project_id": 1
    },
    {
        "project_id": 2
    }
]
```

}

or this

```
    {
    "start_time": "09:00:00",
    "end_time": "18:00:00",
    "rest_time": "01:00:00",
    "worked_time": "08:00:00",
    "is_wfh": true,
    "id": [
        1,
        1
    ],
    "work_day_id": 45,
    "time_cards": [
"project_id": [1, 2]
}
```

In case you need the first scenario, the following code may help you:

```
// This function return an array with: [{project_id: Number}]
function onlyIds(obj) {
  const ids = [];
  // Iterate the obj Array
  obj.forEach(element => {
    // Push a new JSON: "{project_id: 1}" or whatever
    ids.push({ project_id: element.project_id });
  });
  // return an array that only contains the project_id
  return ids;
}

const obj = [
  {
    project_id: 1,
    project_name: 'CDP',
    role: 'PL',
  },
  {
    project_id: 2,
    project_name: 'Admincer',
    role: 'PM',
  },
];
const objCopy = {
  start_time: '09:00:00',
  end_time: '18:00:00',
  rest_time: '01:00:00',
  worked_time: '08:00:00',
  is_wfh: true,
  id: [1, 1],
  work_day_id: 45,
  time_cards: onlyIds(obj),
};
console.log(onlyIds(obj));
console.log(objCopy);
```

I'm pretty sure there should be any more elegant/optimal way (as using any kind of higher-order function I may be missing right now) but as far as I understood, this should do the job.

Comment: I want to replace the "project_id" property with the "project_name" property.

Comment: ' {
  "start_time": "09:00:00",
  "end_time": "18:00:00",
  "rest_time": "01:00:00",
  "worked_time": "08:00:00",
  "time_cards": [
    {
      "duration": "04:00:00",
      "work_log": "sain",
      "project_name": CDP  //not "project_id" here
    },
    {
      "duration": "03:00:00",
      "work_log": "sain02",
      "project_id": 2
    },
    {
      "duration": "01:00:00",
      "work_log": "sain03",
      "project_id": 3
    }
  ]
}'

Comment: Ok so... 
time_cards should look like this: [
    {
      duration: '04:00:00',
      work_log: 'sain',
      project_name: CDP, //not "project_id" here
    },
    { duration: '03:00:00', work_log: 'sain02', project_id: 2 },
    { duration: '01:00:00', work_log: 'sain03', project_id: 3 },
  ]

This means that first element of the array should have project_name instead of project_id? Or you want to exchange project_id with project_name in ALL elements of the array?

Anyway take a closer look to Noelle answer, the map function is a really elegant way to overcome this problem.

Comment: yes , i want to exchange project_id with project_name in ALL elements of the array